# How to fetch all of pages(from pagination) using urllib2.urlopen?

Tags: python, parsing, pagination

I want to fetch all pages and parse them until there is no load-more url in response(link variable). Could any one show me how i can modify the following code so it fetches all the pages till there is no load-more URL in response(link variable) ?

```
import urllib2,re

Fromurl = "https://somesite.com/n/series/123456/";

req = urllib2.Request(Fromurl)
req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
link=response.read()
print "value of link here:"
print link
response.close()

//try to parse response here

#################### here we get next page url###################
matchNextPageUrl =re.findall('loadmore', link, re.UNICODE)
print "value of matchNextPageUrl [0][0]"

print "https://somesite.com/n/series/nexpage"+matchNextPageUrl[0][0]+".sort-number:DESC.pageNumber-1";
```

Comment: Why are you not using a html parser? Can you share the link as there are numerous better ways to so what you are trying

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not expert in using python. Do you mean using html parser to get the next page url from api call ? How to use urllib2.urlopen until there is no next page url on response ?

Comment: I mean parsing html with a regex is a bad idea, there are numerous html parsers you can use that will make it pretty trivial to do what you want and to parse the pages in general.

Comment: how i can keep fetching the page until there is no next page url in response ? should i use while loop ?

Comment: I need to see the page or the html